# how can i solve this ERROR TypeError: this.data.slice is not a function

Tags: angular, leaflet

this.map.on('click',e => {(document.getElementById('latitude') as HTMLInputElement).value =e.latlng.lat;(document.getElementById('longitude') as HTMLInputElement).value =e.latlng.lng; this.lat=e.latlng.lat this.long=e.latlng.lng this.addBuildingForm.controls.latitude.setValue(this.lat)
this.addBuildingForm.controls.longitude.setValue(this.long)
})

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Focus on creating something *reproducible*.

Comment: most likely the scope of 'this' is the funcion itself. try binding it to the component using .bind(this, false);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.